# MySQL - Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'PRIMARY' even no duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql

My table (fs_db.parentlist) contains two keys (pid, mid). 
Now that my SQL codes are here:

```
DELETE FROM fs_db.parentlist WHERE pid = 36479 OR mid = 36479;
DELETE FROM fs_db.parentlist WHERE pid = 36481 OR mid = 36481;

SELECT * FROM fs_db.parentlist WHERE pid = 36479 OR mid = 36479;
SELECT * FROM fs_db.parentlist WHERE pid = 36481 OR mid= 36481;

INSERT INTO fs_db.parentlist (pid, mid) VALUES (36479,36481);
```

As you would see that I have already deleted records before inserting, 
and the SELECT statement returns 0 rows. 
But when I run the INSERT statement, it returns:

Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '36479' for key 'PRIMARY'

Could any one provide some helps?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the table?

Comment: Did you add a unique key at any point?

Comment: @TiesonT. He said he kas unique keys on `pid` and `mid`.

Comment: @Barmar I see where he says "keys" but I don't see where he said they were unique keys.

Comment: @TiesonT. It's obviously unique because he's getting an error about duplicates.

Comment: @PriereLaw Can you paste also the full DDL of `fs_db.parentlist` ? Otherwise ... something is simply missing ..